# jsPlumb click on single item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Is it possible when user click on question 1 from left side and any 1 answer should be select-able not multiple answer.

[image: Left side what i want]

Comment: Show us the code you tried already (you did try something, did you ?) Or is it just "please can you do this for me" ?

Comment: Here is an example : this works fine but with click, you have to click on left then right to answer

http://output.jsbin.com/ajideh/7/

Comment: the link doesn't work, just shows the boxes, no connection working. https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/flowchart/dom.html almost like what you want.

Comment: Example works with Click event first you have to click on left side then answer your question with click on right side.

Answer (score 2):

`maxConnections` is what you need.

```
jsPlumb.makeTarget("el1", {
  maxConnections:3
});
```

References :

http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/connections.html#sourcesandtargets
http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#property_Defaults.MaxConnections
http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_makeTarget

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for answering, Any example Please.

Comment: Hello 
I am very new in JS.
here i tried click on any question and then click on any answer you see an line creates.

http://jsfiddle.net/indianwebdesigner/66869uhy/